# using mysql in Electron

Tags: mysql, node.js, electron

Im trying to use `mysql` in electron but i'm running into this error

```
TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object  
at Socket.write (net.js:667)  
at Protocol.<anonymous> (Connection.js:100)
```

with this code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'host address',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'pw',
    database: 'db name',
  });

con.connect(err => {
    if(err) throw err
})
con.query('select * from BOOKS', (err2, result) => {
    if(err2) {
        throw err2;
    }
    console.log(result);
})
```

if i paste this into a `test.js` file and run it with `node` then it runs 100% fine without errors, so im not really sure where im going wrong here

Comment: are you sure the error is from that code?

Comment: @EMX Yup, if I updated to include more of the stack trace, you can see that it includes Connection.js which is from `mysql`. Also I ran the debugger and inspected the call stack and it came from that code. Also I remove it and it didn't throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns it my issue had something to do with the fact that I was running Angular on electron. if I put that code inside my Angular code it would error out but if I put it in the `index.html` it would run fine.
So I just made a little proxy function in the `index.html` for connecting to the DB and making queries, then i'd jsut call it from inside the Angular app without a problem like `window.mysqlQuery(queryString)`